# How can i validate user input as an array?

Tags: php, html

[image]I am relatively new to PHP. I stored the questions and answers into an array and also stored answers from the user into an array. I am hoping the arrays will iterate and validate itself. However I am getting some problem as when I tried to input the correct answers, it will still display the message that I am wrong. **Question:** Anyone knows how I can compare both arrays correctly? Also how can i display the user input into the text box when it is being submitted? **Text at the top was for me to see what my arrays are storing. The answers are _ -> stores answers I submitted previously (before the page got refreshed) & the real answers are the current question answers. Hope this helps.**

```
<?php 
//to store 4 questions into a new array 
$four_qn = array();  
$message = "" ;
$score = 0;

$ansArray = array();

//store the questions and into a multidimensional array 
$qn_array = array(
    1 => array(
            'Question' => "In which novel of Roald Dahl, the character Willy Wonka can be found?", 
            'Answer'=> "charlie and the chocolate factory"
    ), 
    2 => array(      
            'Question' => "‘West Side Story,’ a musical is based on a tragedy by Shakespeare. Which tragedy is it?", 
            'Answer' =>"romeo and juliet"
    ), 
    3 => array(
            'Question' => "Who became the best-selling author in the 2000s in Britain?",
            'Answer' => "jk rowling"
    ),
    4 => array( 
            'Question' => "What is the name the novel by George Orwell where we find the character ‘Napoleon’?", 
            'Answer' => "animal farm"
    ),
    5 => array( 
            'Question' => "Tweedledum and Tweedledee are two characters of which Children’s book?",
            'Answer' => "alice in wonderland"
    ),
    6 => array( 
            'Question' => "Name the mega-selling writer who has written “Deception Point”?", 
            'Answer' => "dan brown"
    ), 
    7 => array(
            'Question' =>"‘A Brief History of Time’ is a famous book written in 1988. Who is its author?",
            'Answer' => "stephen hawking"
    ), 
    8 => array(
            'Question' => "Who ended his writing career with ‘The Last Tycoon’?", 
            'Answer' => "F scott fitzgerald"
    ),
    9 => array(
            'Question' => "What literary tale contains the phrase “fee, fie, fo, fum”?", 
            'Answer' => "jack and the beanstalk"
    ), 
    10 => array(  
            'Question' => "Theodor Geisel used what pen name when writing his children’s books?",
            'Answer' => "dr seuss")
);

//get four random elements
function getRand($qn) {
    shuffle($qn); //randomize 
    $qn = array_slice($qn, 6); //slice the array to get 4 elements and store into new array 
    return $qn;
}

$four_qn = getRand($qn_array);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
 if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
    $ansArray = $_POST['ans'];  //get submitted answers 
    //if (is_array($ansArray)) {
    foreach ($ansArray as $q => $ans) { //answers from user 
        $ans = stripslashes($ans); 
        if (strlen($ans) > 0) {
            foreach ($four_qn as $q => $correctAns) {   //original answer 
                if (strcasecmp($correctAns['Answer'], $ans)==0) { 
                    $message =  "You are right!" . "<br>";
                    $score += 5; 
                }    
                    else {
                        //$error = $_POST['error'];
                        $message =  "You are wrong.. " . "<br>";
                        $score -= 3; 
                    }    
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "At least write something!";
    }
    unset($ansArray);
} 
?>
```

```html
<body> 

    <!-- title --> 
<div class="header">Literature quiz</div>
    <br><br> 

    <form method="post" action="lit.php"> 
       &nbsp;
    <?php 
    $count = 1;
    while ($count < 5) {
            foreach ($four_qn as $qn => $value) { 
                    echo "<h3 class='count'>$count)</h3>" ; ?>
                <div class="questions">
                    <h3> <?php echo $value['Question'] ;
                    ?>
                    </h3> 
                </div>
    <?php
            //foreach ($ansArray as $ans) { ?>
                <div class="answers">
                    <input type="text" name="ans[]">
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $message ;?></span>
                <br>
                <?php 
                    $count++; ?>
    <?php   //} ?>

    <?php } 
    }; ?>
                </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type= 'submit' name='submit' value="Check answers" class="submit">&nbsp;
    <input type="button" name="attempt" value="Try again">&nbsp;


</form>


</body>
```

Comment: `var_dump($correctAns['Answer'], $ans)` gives what? In the `foreach ($qn_array as $q => $correctAns) {`

Comment: int(0) for the var_dump @user3783243

Comment: There should be 2 values

Comment: When i echo-ed it all it says is int(0).. @user3783243

Comment: Don't echo, it throws output on its own. There should be 2 values. Actually, `echo` doesn't make a difference, https://3v4l.org/hStei vs. https://3v4l.org/dfDNO

Comment: right, ok for eg i input "romeo and juliet". the output is: int(0) string(16) "romeo and juliet". The actual answers of the questions changed to the one i typed? @user3783243

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235549/discussion-between-helpagirlout-and-user3783243).

Comment: Sounds like `$correctAns` is not what you think it contains then. `print_r` or `var_dump` that and take a look.

Comment: I've print_r/var_dump my $correctAns and it tallies with everything that is being displayed on the page with the correct ans... just not sure why my validation is not working